# error when using web services return Json?

Tags: c#, json, web-services, lambda, entity-framework-6

I have a test , a want to get info Table LOCATION in database, i using Web Services and return Json, but it is error.

```
 [WebMethod]
            [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]  
            public List<LOCATIONPARAM> VIEW_LOCATION()
            {
                using (QLTDEntities db = new QLTDEntities())
                {
                    List<LOCATIONPARAM> list = new List<LOCATIONPARAM>();
                    list = db.LOCATIONs.Select(e => new LOCATIONPARAM()
                    {
                        LOCATION_ID = e.LOCATION_ID,
                        LOCATION_NAME = e.LOCATION_NAME,
                        FLAG = e.FLAG
                    }).ToList();
                    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(list);
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the exact error you're having ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your code compile?

Your return type is `List<LOCATIONPARAM>`, but JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize( ) returns a string

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292287(v=vs.110).aspx

Changing the return type to string should work:

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]  
        public string VIEW_LOCATION()
        {
            using (QLTDEntities db = new QLTDEntities())
            {
                List<LOCATIONPARAM> list = new List<LOCATIONPARAM>();
                list = db.LOCATIONs.Select(e => new LOCATIONPARAM()
                {
                    LOCATION_ID = e.LOCATION_ID,
                    LOCATION_NAME = e.LOCATION_NAME,
                    FLAG = e.FLAG
                }).ToList();
                return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(list);
            }
        }
```